# Simulating a second order differential equation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulation

I need a simulation(a moving graph I mean) of a second order differential equation. I have an approximate form of it so not dealing with ODE.Just trying to find V(i,j) matrix with below equation.You can sea that V(i,j) is related by previous value of V(i,j).

[image]

I need to simulate V(z) over time (t). I wrote a code but it didn't work. I really need help,thank you.

Here is my code:

```
totalTime = 100; %mSecond
deltaT=.01; %% deltaT
t=0:deltaT:totalTime;
totallength=10;
deltax=0.01;  %% deltaX  = deltaZ actually
x=0:deltax:totallength;

for i=1:numel(t)-1 

    for x = 2:totallength-1

    dV(x) = ((V(x+1)-2*V(x)+V(x-1))/(deltax*deltax));

    end

    for x = 2:totallength-1
        V(x)=dV(x)+deltaT*dV(x);
    end

    V(1) = V(2) ; V(totallength) = V(totallength-1) ;

    plot_Vm(i,1:totallength) = V(1:totallength) ;
    plot(plot_Vm(i, : ), deltax*(0:totallength-1) ) ; % plot Vm vs space
    drawnow ;

end
```

Comment: Is there a question? What kind of simulation are your performing, i.e., how are you integrating you differential equations? Better commenting would help. A plot is not a simulation itself – it displays the output from a simulation. Is the question with animating the results or with integrating the equations? You might look at [`comet`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/comet.html) and the example code there.

Comment: Actually I am trying to find V(i,j) matrix with the equation above. I mean V(1,1)=3,V(1,2)=5...etc. DeltaZ and DeltaT is constant.So I am using 2 FOR loops to find V(i,j)'s.And ploting it with 'drawnow' command.

Comment: So I suppose `j` indexes the discretized variable z, correct? And in your code you specify that `j` can take on values from 1 to 10. But how would you deal with the borders of your space, what kind of boundary conditions do you assume? It appears you just do not compute `dV` at the edges; would you then assume that `dV(1)` and dV(end)` are 0? Moreover, what are the initial values of `V` you'd like to start from?

Comment: For the boundary conditions,V(1)=V(2) and V(totallength) = V(totallength-1)